# How to copy an existing Hyper-V VM to Azure (without Site Recovery)?

Tags: azure, hyper-v

We would like to test a setup of 3 existing VMs (running in our Hyper-V Cloud) in Azure.

Migrating to Azure using Site Recovery would be comparatively easy; but we don't want to *migrate* / deactivate the local VMs in any way (they are critical in production).

Rather, we want to make copies of them, move those to Azure and play/test with them there (just for performance testing and cost measuring).

I couldn't find any easy solution in the net; usually there are quite complex Powershell scripts required to do even part of this. In comparison, AWS offers a (seemingly) really simple solution (AWS Server Migration Service) - can't believe that this is not possible on Azure?

Thanks! Peter

Comment: I think I just found a potential answer to my question: We could copy/clone the VMs **locally**, and them migrate the clones to Azure using Site Recovery. Anybody out there who has done this / endorses this?

Comment: You can just upload your fixed disk VHDs as blobs and create new VMs in Azure using them. See [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed).

Comment: That's just very time-consuming, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar service called Azure Migration Service that will help you asess you servers workload, costs and so on. When it comes to the "migrate" part which uses Azure Site Recovery an easy option is to just stop the sync when you have synced your vm's. Your on-prem servers is online and working and you have oflfine copies in Azure.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/migration/

Another option is to use Azure Backup, backup your on-prem VM's and restore them to new VM's in Azure.
https://newsignature.com/articles/three-ways-restore-azure-iaas-vms/
[image]

Comment: The term "Migration Service" might be a bit overblown/marketing-motivated. In essence, it is still the old ASR - and ASR e.g. doesn't allow to start a replicated VM without shutting down the source VM (at least that's what the above linked documentation says, even through a test failover). This was the origin of my question: How can we test it without having ANY side effect on the current production environment (which must be always on)?